# What is a sufficient decrease in the merit function?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

As far as I understand, the merit function measures how far the data is from the fitted function.

I am calulcating the second partial derivative of a function, and then numerically finding its maxima and minima with FindRoot.

It always outputs an error message along the lines of:

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 30.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Which makes me think: can I just change the settings of the merit function? I.e., lower the threshold for what is considered a *sufficient* change? And by the way, what is the default setting?

---

**CODE**:

```
k = 2 π;
k1 = {k, 0};
k2 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5]. k1];
k3 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5]. k2];
k4 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5] .k3];
k5 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5] .k4];
E1[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k1.{x, y} - α1]
E2[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k2.{x, y} - α1]
E3[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k3.{x, y} - α1]
E4[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k4.{x, y} - α1]
E5[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k5.{x, y} - α1]
Eges[x_, y_] := 
 E1[x, y, 1, 0] + E2[x, y, 1, 0] + E3[x, y, 1, 0] + E4[x, y, 1, 0] + 
  E5[x, y, 1, 0]
IIges[x_, y_] := 
  Conjugate[Eges[x, y]] Eges[x, y] // ComplexExpand // 
   Simplify; (* can't differentiate Conjugate, had to change this *)
{dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = 
  D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}]; (* calculating partial derivatives *)
hes[x_, y_] = 
  D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}, 
    2}]; (* Hessian matrix: Second derivative matrix *)

(* Find critical points *)
crit = Cases[
   Normal[ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
     ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
   Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
      FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
        dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
         y0}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 20, MaxIterations -> 1000]), ∞];

(* Identify points as minima, maxima or saddle points *)
hl = hes @@@ crit;
mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl; (*pick minima*)
mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl); (*pick maxima*)
sdp = Thread[mnp ⊽ mxp];(*saddle points are leftovers*)

(* Finding coordinates of critical points *)
mini = Pick[crit, mnp];
maxi = Pick[crit, mxp];
sadl = Pick[crit, sdp];

(* Plot stuff!
   I changed the Image Size because it was too small *)
{Legended[
  ContourPlot[IIges[x, y], {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
   ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3], ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", 
   Contours -> 15, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], {Cyan, Point[mini]}, {Orange, Point[maxi]}}], 
  PointLegend[{Cyan, Orange}, {"Minima", "Maxima"}]], 
 Show[Plot3D[IIges[x, y], {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", Mesh -> 15, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Cyan, Sphere[mini, 1/20]}, {Orange, 
      Sphere[maxi, 1/20]}} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, IIges[x, y]}],
  ImageSize -> Scaled[0.43], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False]}
```

Comment: It would help to have an example to play with.

Comment: I don't have time to write a fully fleshed-out answer at the moment, but did you notice that `Conjugate[Eges[x, y]] == Eges[-x, -y]`?

Comment: that fixed it, thanks. But why?

Comment: actually sorry no, it didn't fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the merit function:

> Both step control methods [line search and trust region] were developed originally with minimization in mind. However, they apply well to finding roots for nonlinear equations when used with a merit function. In the Wolfram Language, the 2-norm merit function `r(x).r(x)` is used. -- [Introduction to Step Control](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationIntroductionStepControl.html)

The "sufficient decrease" criterion is controlled by `AccuracyGoal`.  We can check by solving for one of the OP's troublesome points and determining how far from zero the merit function is.  Its square-root should be closer to zero than `10^-ag`, where `ag` is the setting for `AccuracyGoal`.

```
sol = Block[{x0 = 1.5107119013044863`, y0 = -1.6225965143185352`}, 
  FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]},
    {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], y0}},
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20, MaxIterations -> 100]]
```

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 30.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

```
(*
  {\[FormalX] ->  1.51066343431975599208008475284,
   \[FormalY] -> -1.62258704517760281788841182199}
*)

{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]} . 
 {dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]} /. sol  (* merit function *)
ag = -Log10[%]/2                                                  (* AccuracyGoal *)
(*
  0.065933684103633462001724717
  0.59044632849264420129427203
*)

Block[{x0 = 1.5107119013044863`, y0 = -1.6225965143185352`}, 
 FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]},
  {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], y0}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> 20, 
  MaxIterations -> 100]]
(*
  {\[FormalX] ->  1.51066407892396160887133952303,
   \[FormalY] -> -1.62258717078894941887987024328}
*)
```

A slight higher setting, `AccuracyGoal -> acc + 1*^-6`, results in the `FindRoot::lstol` message.

Of course, this change does not make the solution returned any closer to a root.  It just hides the fact that the objective function is not very close to zero.  `Quiet` has the same effect. :-)

Comment: Very nice answer indeed. This kind of confusion is so frequent that I believe this Q/A should be upvoted to death. Good work